# Implementing Access Control over data in Java on Windows

Tags: java, mysql, data-security

We are making a windows desktop application using Java FX. We will be storing the data in a local MySQL server (on the same computer). We want to ensure, the user can edit/create data only with our application. And cannot damage or modify the information on their own.

Any possible solution to achieve this?

Comment: Make sure only your application know the MySQL password. But you're going to have trouble with administration, backup, etc.

Comment: @EJP I was wondering, someone could brute-force or do something else, and get the Root password for MySQL. Any suggestion regarding that?

Comment: @EJP Is embedded MySQL any good for this?